Where are anonymous callback functions to setTimeout stored?
I have a simple program that looks like this:
console.log("Start of the program execution!");

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("I ran after a second!");
}, 1000);

console.log("The end of the file!");

Then, the question I have is: Where does the anonymous function live while the timer is running and the function is not put onto the call stack?
If I had a normal function definition, the code would look like this:
function doSth()
{
    console.log("I ran after a second!");
}

console.log("Start of the program execution!");

setTimeout(doSth, 1000);

console.log("The end of the file!");

then, the function doSth() would still live in the global memory after the call stack became empty and thus the setTimeout() could use its reference to call it after the set time. This arrangement makes perfect sense to me. The problems arise when I use an anonymous function and make some observations.
For some observations, I first put the debugger on line 5 of the program; the console.log("The end of the file!");. Then I take a look at the Scope of the Developer Tools. The anonymous function is nowhere to be seen.
For the next observation, I put the debugger on the console.log() inside the setTimeout() function, which is line 3 of the program. Then indeed the call stack has the anonymous function on it when we are running it.
Thus, these two observations bring forward the confusion for me. If the anonymous function was not present in the global memory AFTER the setTimeout() was called, then how can it be pushed to the call stack when the setTimeout() finishes its job? Does the function "go with" the setTimeout() to the webAPIs domain and then come back from there?

There's no essential difference between a named and anonymous function. Either way, you're just passing the function object to setTimeout(), and it saves that object.

The function doesn't need to be in any scope. It's just an object that the timeout object holds a reference to.

It's no different from passing an unnamed array or object to a function, which then saves that data in one of its local variables.

@Barmar Makes sense. The question I have is: where IS the function (or function object, as you call it) stored? I can't see it anywhere in global memory, and suddenly it appears on the call stack!

The event loop has a list of timer objects in some internal variable. The timer objects contain references to their callback functions. This list is not exposed in any public interface.

@Barmar Again! Agreed! "The timer objects contain references to their callback functions." For sure they should. But where IS that function in global memory? The timer object contain references. References to where? I can't see it in memory.

You could say it's just stored on the heap, and then a reference is made to it.

logically, the code remains text put "on standby" during the delay, and this code only appears when the JS interpreter takes care of it

@Keith That does make sense. Could you provide some more info on how setTimeout() works under the hood? Does setTimeout() "know" where the function is in the heap? Do all webAPIs "know" about the objects we provide to them and their actual position in the heap?

"The anonymous function is nowhere to be seen." - where did you look? If you did a heap snapshot, you would find it.

"Do all webAPIs "know" about the objects we provide to them and their actual position in the heap?" - they don't know or care any more than other APIs. They hold a reference, and that reference is marked as a garbage collection root as long as it is held by the (asynchronous) webAPI implementation.

The HTML Standard defines the initialisation steps for setTimeout. It includes the definition of a task in step 5:


Let task be a task that runs the following substeps:
    [1. ... 2. ...]

If handler is a Function, then invoke handler




In other words, the task created by setTimeout holds a reference to the callback (handler) inside a task object -- no matter whether it is anonymous or named. By general principle in JavaScript, whenever an object has at least one reference, it will not be candidate for garbage collection.
When the timeout period has expired, a step is executed -- called the completionStep --, described in step 11 in the same procedure:


Let completionStep be an algorithm step which queues a global task on the timer task source given global to run task.


The actual execution of that algorithm step is described in run steps after timeout.
But the essential thing is that the agent (host, webbrowser) that provides setTimeout has a reference to the callback function during the time of calling setTimeout and the eventual execution of the callback.
Evaluation order
When the engine evaluates an expression that has a function call in it (in this case a call of setTimeout), then first the arguments are evaluated and only then that function is called. In your example code the order of evaluation is:

The callback function (object):
() => {
    console.log("I ran after a second!");
}

It is in this step that a function object is allocated. Then:

1000
This happens to be a simple primitive value.

The setTimeout expression:
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("I ran after a second!");
}, 1000);

At this point setTimeout is called, and it gets the reference to the function object created in step 1, and the primitive value 1000.


It is not setTimeout that creates this callback object in memory. This happens by normal evaluation order and is not specific to setTimeout.
If setTimeout would not do anything with the first argument it gets, then when it returns, the callback function object created in step 1 would no longer have a reference to it. Its memory could be freed any time the garbage collector runs. But as setTimeout copies the function reference into non-local memory (in a task object), that callback function remains available for later execution: it has a reference to it that outlives the setTimeout call.

So, if the function already exists in the global memory, then the task object has the reference to that function, and if it is an anonymous function, FIRST, it is stored in the heap by the setTimeout() and THEN its reference is stored in the task object. Is that what you're trying to say? Who does the work of storing that function in the heap? Is it JavaScript or setTimeout()?

The function already exists in memory before setTimeout is called. This is the general principle in programming languages: when you have f(x, y), then x is evaluated, then y is evaluated and then f is called. The evaluation of a function expression results in a function object, which is allocated on the heap like any other JavaScript object. setTimeout is called and gets a reference to that memory. This reference it then copies into its task object property so that it is not garbage collected when setTimeout returns.

Whoa! So, when I ran the setTimeout(), the anonymous function was in the local scope of setTimeout(), which then added that function from its local scope to the task object, and thus, even when the setTimeout() popped out of the stack, thus having its local scope also destroyed, the function was still in the task object and hence, it was referenced from there when the callback was called after the set time. Is that precisely it? It DOES make absolute sense. Thank you very much. I will accept the answer now, for all my questions have been answered and my queries fulfilled. :-)

Yes, it is like you write.

You can imagine that setTimeout() and setInterval() are implemented something like this:


class Timer {
  static allTimers = {};
  static timerId = 0;

  constructor(timeout, func, interval) {
    this.timerId = ++timerId;
    this.timeout = timeout;
    this.func = func;
    this.interval = interval;
    this.expire_time = Date.now() + timeout;
    this.allTimers[timerId] = this;
    addTimerToEventLoop(this);
  }
  
  clear(id) {
    let timer = this.allTimers[id];
    if (timer) {
      removeTimerFromEventLoop(timer);
    }
}

function setTimeout(timeout, func) {
  let newTimer = new Timer(timeout, func, false);
  return newTimer.timerId;
}

function setInterval(timeout, func) {
  let newTimer = new Timer(timeout, func, true);
  return newTimer.timerId;
}



The functions addTimerToEventLoop() and removeTimerFromEventLoop() are the internval interface with the event loop that makes it run them on the timed schedule.
The functions are held in the func property of each Timer object. If the Timer class were actually visible to user code, instead of being internal to the JavaScript engine, you would be able to find them on Timer.allTimers.
